# Cross-Site XMLHttpRequest - When?

Tags: xmlhttprequest, xss

Can anyone who's following the specification more closely and has experience with how these things usually work estimate when [Cross-Site XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-cors-20090317/) will become a Recommendation and start getting supported by the browsers?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been following the specification.

Given that IE6 is still in common use 5 years after IE7 came out, it'll take a long time (10 years?) before this can be reliably counted on to exist in browsers.

In the mean time, consider using [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) for non-sensitive data.  Granted, you shouldn't be transmitting sensitive information without encrypting it to begin with...

Comment: Heck, we're still stuck with developing for IE5. Our wheels turn *very* slowly, grinding along on axles of solid incompetence.

Answer (score 0):

> when Cross-Site XMLHttpRequest will become a Recommendation

When:

- It is ready
- There are two independent, compatible implementations
- The wheels of bureaucracy have turned far enough

> start getting supported by the browsers

Ages ago. [Firefox 3.5 supports it](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_Access_Control), for instance.